# Дубли событий в GTM и GA4

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Есть магазин на OpenCart. К нему подключена GA4. После создания события "покупки" (когда пользователь переходит на страницу благодарности) получаю странную статистику.  Количество событий в раз больше количества пользователей. То есть происходит дубли события. Сначала создавала событие сразу в GA4. Но при тестирование, после попадания на страницу "благодарности" и переходе на любую другую, оно срабатывало повторно. Решилось это созданием событий через Google Tag Manager. Но все равно замечаю что событий на 20%-30% больше чем пользователей. Думаю, это может быть связано с обновлением пользователем страницы благодарности, сохранением и заходом повторно на странницу, либо когда мобильный пользователь после оформления заказа возвращается назад и треггерит повторно событие.

Думала можно решить в Google Tag Manager создав группу событий и регистрировать событие после того как пользователь нажмет на кнопку оформления заказа и перейдет на страницу благодарности, но оказывается что группа триггеров будет работать только в пределах одной страницы.

Может кто-то подскажет как решают дюнную проблему? Может в Google Tag Manager можно настраивать срабатывание событие один раз для одного сеанса, или одного пользователя? Либо как в примере выше, отследить нажатие на кнопку и переход на странницу?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы настраиваете цель на посещение страницы Спасибо, то дубли будут в любом случае при возращении покупателя на эту страницу. Лучше настраивать цель на покупку на успешную отправку формы на предыдущем этапе оформления заказа, либо через слой данных (DataLayer), если он есть - последнее предпочтительней, так как вы сможете передать так же данные по заказу (цена, номер, товары).